# How to replace lower/upper triangular elements of a matrix?

Tags: r

My question:

```
Amat <- diag(4)
```

I would like to replace all the lower triangular values of `Amat` (i.e. `Amat[2,1]`, `Amat[3,1]`, `Amat[3,2]`, and so on) with a value I choose (e.g. `NA`).

Obviously I do not want to replace each element one by one.

Could you show me the most efficient way to do it with a single command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` what you are looking for ?

These functions are in R base.

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty well documented in the docs for `upper.tri`.

```
Amat[upper.tri(Amat)] <- NA
Amat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    0    1   NA   NA
# [3,]    0    0    1   NA
# [4,]    0    0    0    1
```

Of course, `Amat[lower.tri(Amat)] <- NA` would do the same for converting the lower triangle to `NA`s.

Comment: Replace `upper.tri` with `lower.tri` if you want to do the same for the lower triangle, of course.

Comment: That comment should really form part of your answer.

Comment: @Andrie, done. I figured since they had asked for upper or lower, one would suffice. but always better to be more specific and not assume, I guess.

Comment: Is it possible to not show the lower triangle ? . Replacing NA by NULL doesnt work.

Comment: @Anusha, wrapping the output in `as.table` would suppress the printing of the `NA` values.

Comment: This doesnt work. Returns a set of alphabets. A to N2 which is the lemgth of vectors in the matrix. Just using xtable suppresses the NA but dont know how write to a csv file.