# Replacing pair of element of symmetric matrix with NA

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a positive definite symmetric matrix. Pasting the matrix generated using the following code:

```
set.seed(123)
m <- genPositiveDefMat(
    dim = 3, 
    covMethod = "unifcorrmat",
    rangeVar = c(0,1) )

x <- as.matrix(m$Sigma)
  diag(x) <- 1

x

#Output
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.2432303 -0.4110525
[2,] -0.2432303  1.0000000 -0.1046602
[3,] -0.4110525 -0.1046602  1.0000000
```

Now, I want to run the matrix through iterations and in each iteration I want to replace the symmetric pair with NA. For example,

Iteration 1:
x[1,2] = x[2,1] <- NA

Iteration2:
x[1,3] = x[3,1] <- NA

and so on....

My idea was to check using a for loop

Prototype:

```
for( r in 1:nrow(x)
for( c in 1:ncol(x)

if x[r,c]=x[c,r]<-NA

else

x[r,c]
```

The issue with my code is for row 1 and column 1, the values are equal hence it sets to 0 (which is wrong). Also, the moment it is not NA it comes out of the loop.

Appreciate any help here.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `upper.tri(x)` and `lower.tri(x)` might help you to remove one side of the symmetry.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176164/how-to-replace-lower-upper-triangular-elements-of-a-matrix

Comment: Thanks. But this replaces all at once. I want it in iterations. AFter every iteration, I am passing this output to some other function. Hence, I want it in steps and not all at once. In a sense, in step one only the first pair - 1,2 and 2,1 should be replaced with NA and the rest matrix should be as it is

Comment: Change every off-diagonal term to `NA` and before change terms, pull out those value is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the replacement done iteratively, you can use the indexes of values represented by `upper.tri(x)/lower.tri` to do the replacements pair-by-pair. That will allow you to pass the results to a function before/after each replacement, e.g.:

```
idx <- which(lower.tri(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)
sel <- cbind(
  replace(mat, , seq_along(mat))[ idx ],
  replace(mat, , seq_along(mat))[ idx[,2:1] ]
)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    4 ##each row represents the lower/upper pair
#[2,]    3    7
#[3,]    6    8

for( i in seq_len(nrow(sel)) ) {
    mat[ sel[i,] ] <- NA
    print(mean(mat, na.rm=TRUE))
}
#[1] 0.2812249
#[1] 0.5581359
#[1] 1
```

Comment: there seems to one thing with this code. this works well for 3*3 matrix. But for dimensions 4*4 and beyond, the position of lower.tri and upper.tri doesn't seems to match

For example, the positions for 4*4 matrix are (2,5) , (3,9) , (4,10) , (7,13) , (8,14) , (12,15).


@thelatemail

Comment: The reason, I understand is due to mismatch between row and column selection in the lower.tri and upper.tri matrix. Unfortunately, there is no parameter like "byrow=T/F" in lower.tri and/or upper.tri

An alternative function is upperTriangle and LowerTriange function in package gdata. However, unlike lower.tri and upper,tri it gives the value directly. Hence, getting the position becomes difficult

Comment: @RogKa - try now, i think i've fixed it

Comment: Perfect. Looks great. thanks